# ADFS Authentication in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: adfs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like try out MVC 6 on a new project, but one of the requirements is using ADFS for authentication.  Is this possible yet with MVC6?  I tried using Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation in an MVC6 project, but I get the following error:

Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'Asp.Net,Version=v5.0':
  Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation 3.0.0

Does anyone know if there's a ASP5MVC6 compatible package for ADFS auth?

Comment: I do know that you can get around this error by placing the dependency in the dnx451 framework dependencies.  You also have to wrap all of the code that uses this dependency with `#if !DNXCORE50 //CODE HERE #endif`.  So not the greatest solution.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET 5 (including ASP.NET MVC 6) does not yet have support for ADFS authentication, but it is in the plans (I work on the ASP.NET team).

Comment: How soon? ADFS authentication is killing me?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a timeline. You can still use ASP.NET MVC 5.x and Web API 2.x if you need ADFS authentication immediately.

Comment: Ha, I always find a clue after I post.  https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/43, is a post about this topic, it looks like it is in the backlog still.

Comment: A preview is now available. See issue 43 linked above.